# Add a character after each letter in a string without using str object methods?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, character

How can I alter a given string in the below manner without using any str object methods, like `.join()` etc?

```
example : 'MOHAMED' >>>>> 'M*O*H*A*M*E*D'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without using any function in Python"?

Comment: In Python nearly everything you do calls a function or method.

Comment: And how are you going to get the result without using the `print()` function?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.join()` - not sure what you mean by "without using any function" - I assume you mean without defining a function.

```
>>> s = 'MOHAMED'
>>> '*'.join(s)
'M*O*H*A*M*E*D'
```

Or with a for-loop:

```
s = 'MOHAMED'
rv = ''

for c in s:
    rv += c + '*'

rv = rv[:-1]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
'M*O*H*A*M*E*D'
```

Comment: @SifeddineMohamed see updated - not sure how you'd use `if` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
source = 'MOHAMED'
starred = ''
for char in source:
    starred += char + '*'
starred = starred[:-1] # cut last '*'
```

OR

```
source = 'MOHAMED'
starred = ''
for index, char in enumerate(source):
    starred += char
    if index < len(source) - 1:
        starred += '*'
```